# Export-CSV fails when used without the pipeline

Tags: powershell

I can import the following file just fine, `c:\temp\myFile.csv`:

```
document, status
"doc1", 0
"doc2", 0
"doc3", 0
```

But attempting to export back the object without the use of the pipeline saves out completely unrelated data:

```
$docs = Import-Csv -Path "c:\temp\myFile.csv"
Export-Csv -path "C:\temp\myFile2.csv" -InputObject $docs
```

This is what is saved to the file:

```
"Length","LongLength","Rank","SyncRoot","IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Count"
"3","3","1","System.Object[]","False","True","False","3"
```

Using the pipeline works, the expected data is saved to the file:

```
$docs = Import-Csv -Path "c:\temp\myFile.csv"
$docs| Export-Csv -path "C:\temp\myFile2.csv"



"document","status"
"doc1","0"
"doc2","0"
"doc3","0"
```

I am on PowerShell 7.4/Windows 11

Comment: `-InputObject` is not meant to be used manually. It is a parameter meant to be bound from pipeline.

Comment: For a general discussion of the behaviors around `-InputObject`, see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).